# Passing data from a datagrid to form and inserting it into the database

Tags: c#, mysql

This Button passes data to a form named Check_Out to another form named BorrowBook

```
    private void RentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BorrowBook borrow = new BorrowBook();


        borrow.BookIDtextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        borrow.AFirstnameTextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        borrow.ConditionTextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        borrow.BookNTextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        borrow.EdTextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();

        borrow.PriceTextBox.Text = CheckOutDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();

        borrow.Show();



    }
```

This button sends the data from BorrowBook to the database but no data is saving to the database. only the Datepickers save to the database as they have nothing to do with the data being pass to this form from the datagrid.

```
    private void Rentbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Book_Class book_ = new Book_Class();


        if (book_.SaveRental(book_))
        {
            book_.BookID = int.Parse(BookIDtextBox.Text);
            book_.price = double.Parse(PriceTextBox.Text);
            book_.school_ID = int.Parse(RenteeIDtextBox.Text);
            book_.rentDate = RentedDateTimePicker.Value;
            book_.returnDate = ReturnDateTimePicker.Value;



            MessageBox.Show("Record saved");
        }
        else
        { MessageBox.Show(this, "Oops, something went wrong, please try again or contact administrator", "ERROR"); }

        this.Close();

    }
```

Comment: if `getBookInfo` is supposed to get the book info *and return it* it should not be a void method

Comment: _it's not going to the database_ - there is no code in your question that would **put** it in a database..

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: @stuartd I have other forms which are sending data to the database

Comment: @Disaffected1070452 Okay I'm gonna create a function that returns it

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya I am trying to send data to the database from a form I inserted from a datagrid but it's giving me null values in the database not the values from the datagrid

Comment: Made some changes to the code